# What is Dharma according to the Purva Mimamsa Sutras?

Tags: dharma, reference-request

I remember (vaguely) reading a sutra (from the Purva Mimamsa Sutras) that defined what Dharma is, however I have lost that sutra so could anybody please point out that sutra? Also I am not asking what Dharma is according to the Bhagavad Gita or the Upanishads or the Vedas or any other scripture beside the Purva Mimamsa sutras. So in other words only Purva Mimamsa sutras for defining Dharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it within Pada 1, 2nd Adhikarana sutra 2 which reads:

> 2. Dharma or Duty is that which, being desirable, is indicated (or taught) by Vedic injunction.